# Wordpress Images, Header Videos and Carousel is not working live but perfect on Local Host Is It FTP? Filezilla?

Tags: uploads

the website works perfect on localhost. But the Wordpress Images, Header Videos and Carousel is not working live. Could it be Filezilla, the FTP?

I tried everything!

My client is waiting and I lied I'm not capable to do this! But this must get done NOW!

Comment: have you updated your WordPress URL since moving the site live? Did you copy the local DB to the live site and not change the site URLS? https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Yes, I'm at wits end now!

Comment: Just to confirm, you’ve properly changed all URLs via the database with a search a replace tool and not just the URLs via WP settings?

Comment: What @SammyTheSalmon says. Plugins usually store links to images in the database, often with the full pathname. If you merely exported the local database and imported it on the remote server, these will still point to your local server path, and fail.

Comment: which search and replace tools would you recommend?

Comment: what error do you get on your live site?  It is not clear from the question what you mean by images not working.  Do you see a broken image icon instead of the image on the page?  If you did you inspect your image location on the page to see if you have any css errors, or image loading errors?

Comment: It works on localhost but simply does not display or just, disappears live.

Comment: Have you tried any of the search and replace methods as per my answer? Are there any console errors via your browsers developer tools?

Answer (score 1):

You should change all URLs in the database from your local url to your production (live) URL.

You can do this using a plugin like [Better Search and Replace](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/).

Alternatively, if you can't access WP Admin, you can use something like [this script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), which should be uploaded directly to the root of your WP install. It’s important to follow the instructions and remove after use.

Once the process is complete, clear your permalinks and you should be good to go.